# Ajax post to database doesn't post anything

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post

I know this has been asked before, but I can seem to find an solution that fixes the problem in my case. I'm trying to post data to a Mysql database with an an Ajax post

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="message" name="message">
    <<input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
</form>
```

**Ajax post**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var message = $("#message").val();
        var data = "message=" + message;
        console.log(data);
        if(message != ''){
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "classes/messages.php",
                data: data,
                succes: function(){
                    alert("succes");
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

**PHP code**

```
class messages{
    function getMessages(){
        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO messages(message, time, user_id)
                    VALUES('$message', 'now()', '12')")or die(mysqli_error($con));
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
}

$messages = new Messages();
$messages->getMessages();
```

Everytime I submit the form nothing happends, not even an php error appears. I've checked the Ajax post and both console.logs return the correct value, so I think the variable is reachable.

I've also checked if the php function is executed at all, which is the case.

Comment: Try to check the XHRs from the Network tab in the Developer Tools or Firebug. You can find there all the information you want: headers, posted data , received data, etc.

Comment: put an error handler in the ajax request body (just in case). Also; you should check your code against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var message = $("#message").val();
            var data = "message=" + message;
            console.log(data);
            if(message != ''){
                console.log(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                url: "classes/messages.php",
                    data: data,
                    success: function(){
                        alert("succes");
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="message" name="message">
        <input type="button" value="Send" id="submit">
    </form>
</body>
    </html>
```

and

```
<?php
class messages{
    function getMessages(){
        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO messages(message, time, user_id)
                    VALUES('$message', 'now()', '12')")or die(mysqli_error($con));
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
}

$messages = new Messages();
$messages->getMessages();
```

Basically I changed `input type='button'` from `'submit' . Since it was a submit button, the ajax call was never done, instead the form was submitting.

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't think the input type would make such a difference

Comment: the curious thing is, the data gets post to the database, but the success funcion isn't executed, have you any idea why?

Comment: @user3164891 You had made a typing mistake, you had typed 'succes' instead of 'success'. I corrected it in my answer

Comment: Aah I must have overlooked that. I'm used to type it like succes, because its spelled that way in my language ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this shorthand method instead:

```
var message = "message=" + $("#message").val();
$("#submit").on("click", function(ev)){
    $.post("classes/messages.php", {message: message}, 'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("succes");       
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("Fail");
        return false;
    }).always();
}
```

Use `on` it's better and recommended than just trigger the function on the selector itself.